# VB.NET : Split word. no delimiter

Tags: vb.net, split, delimiter

I have word : "Banana". And i want it to split into :

```
B
a
n
a
n
a
```

But how? If I don't write delimiter it gaves me error, but when i write delimiter like " " there's no useful results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
Dim test = "Banana"

Dim ar = (From ch In test Select ch).ToArray()

For Each ch As Char In ar
   Console.WriteLine(ch)
Next
```

OR

```
Dim ar=test.AsEnumerable().ToArray()
```